# How to add a day in Vertica

Tags: java, vertica

In sql world we have "adddate()" function to add certain value on the given day. for instance I can say

```
select adddate('2016-2-28',2) as my_day;
```

and the out put will be '2016-03-01'

In Vertica world we don't have adddate() function. We actually have ADD_MONTHS but not ADD_DAYS.

so my question is how are we going to add a day in Vertica

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vertica is clever enough to understand the following:

```
SQL> select '2016-02-28'::date + 2 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add a couple of additional approaches. These are nice if you need to support both timestamps and dates. Additionally, I've seen more support for INTERVAL in other DBMS so if you need cross DBMS support you might want to consider INTERVAL. NOTE: You may need to cast back to date if you need the result to be a date data type.

**Using [TIMESTAMPADD](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/TIMESTAMPADD.htm) function**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD('day', 1, '2020-02-28');
```

(if you need a date returned)

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD('day', 1, '2020-02-28')::date;
```

**Using INTERVAL**

```
SELECT '2016-02-28'::date + INTERVAL '1 day';
```

(if you need a date returned)

```
SELECT ('2016-02-28'::date + INTERVAL '1 day')::date;
```